# Vaadin fields' values are lost using sendKeys in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, vaadin, selenium-ide

We would like to automatically test a web java application generated by vaadin.
We are using Selenium IDE - as first, might be the final step. We do not would like to turn to Selenide, yet, just simply use Selenium IDE.
We fill in all vaadin fields by sendKeys:

`click | id=field1`

`sendKeys | id=field1 | Fieldcontent`

`sendKeys | id=field1 | ${KEY_TAB}`

`click | id=field2`

`sendKeys | id=field2 | Fieldcontent`

`sendKeys | id=field2 | ${KEY_TAB}`

`click | id=save`

After pressing Save button we receive an error message that field1 and field2 is empty.
Simply the vaadin java application doesn't see the value which is sent by sendKey, or with type Selenium commands. But strange because they are there.
FF firebug shows net event if we do the same manually:
Enter value into field1, press tab key, fill in field2 and press save button.
If we click manually into field1 and field2 after testautomation failed, save works.
Seems that manual click and/or selenium click command are different also pressing Tab button manually and sending tab by sendKeys ${KEY_TAB}

How it is possible to fill in vaadin fields by selenium so that necessary events are called and Save button saves the field contents only in Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `type` command instead of `sendKeys`

You can also remove the step wherein TAB key is pressed (Unless of course it is also a part of your test). Selenium IDE automatically inputs characters to fields even without telling the program to focus on the targeted input field.

Comment: This answer should be accepted.
For all that don't know `type` is not `WebElement`'s method. You must use `selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);` and than `selenium.type("css=<selector>", value)`.